# mysql selecting two columns from two tables in one statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been looking if an this has been answered before in SO, but I could not find any.

I have basically two tables in one database. Table `member_privileges`1 keeps users reputation, and table 2 keeps user details. They look roughly like this.

```
mysql> describe member_privileges; 
   +---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
        | Field                     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
        +---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
        | id                        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
        | username                  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
        | can_comment               | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
        | can_create_articles       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
        | can_edit_articles         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
        | can_edit_timeline         | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
        | can_remove_comments       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
        | can_upload_profile_images | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
        | can_upload_article_images | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
        | can_approve_new_articles  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
        | can_freez_articles        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
        +---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and this is the `users` table.

```
mysql> describe users;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| age            | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| country        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| link           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| reg_date       | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ip             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| gender         | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| about          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_activated   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| activation_key | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| image_path     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So, in one page for example, I am trying to check if user `'john'` has a `can_edit_articles` permission set. So, if in `member_privileges` a `username` "john" has a `can_edit_articles` set to 1, then that user can edit.

The problem is checking those details at one. Unlike running two queries like I am doing it now.

```
$email = $_SESSION['email']; 

$get_user = "SELECT id, username FROM members WHERE email = $email; 

$can_user_edit = "SELECT can_edit_articles FROM member_privileges WHERE $email = ?;
```

So, as you can see I am running two queries, and I would like to know if there is any way to run those within one mysql statement. 
...

Comment: This is a basic `join` query.  Are you familiar with the `join` syntax?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Unfortunately no. I was thinking that might be it, but the syntax seemed a little difficult.

Comment: Sidenote: Since we're most likely dealing with a string, quote the email variable `WHERE email = '$email'` if that's your actual code.

Comment: This is a very good guide http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins if you want to read up on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an inner join and prevent your sql statements from sql injection

If you would like to select the id, username and can_edit_articles values:

```
"SELECT m.id, m.username, p.can_edit_articles  
 FROM members m inner join member_privileges p  
 ON m.username=p.username WHERE m.email = '$email'"
```

Comment: No that PHP was an example only. But how do I use inner join?

Comment: `$email` that needs to be quoted, since it's more than likely going to be a string and not an integer.

Comment: You're welcome. I made a slight edit in the answer. Extra quote. @Contax

Comment: You have the wrong join condition, the `id` is the primary key of each respective table.  You need to join on `username`.

Comment: @user2974830 why do you have those `m` `p` prefixes? I don't have those in my db

Comment: @Marc Yeah you are right, but maybe contax should change his Database and create user Ids and not use username in both tables. I will change it.
Contax: You can "create" those prefixes in a sql statement. it's easier to access columns like this. you could also use member_privileges.column_name

Comment: Agreed, the `id` in the `member_privileges` table should be the user id in the `members` table with a foreign key relationship.  The problem with the current design is that if a user changes their id, one needs to alter two tables, which may make it harder to maintain data integrity.

Answer (score 1):

You should use JOIN in your query.  Like this:

```
SELECT can_edit_articles FROM member_privileges 
P LEFT JOIN  members M ON P.username = M.username WHERE email = '$email'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$email = $_SESSION['email']; 

$can_user_edit = "SELECT can_edit_articles FROM member_privileges  
                  WHERE username = (SELECT username FROM users WHERE email = '$email')";
```

Comment: Variables such as an email is more than likely to be a string, therefore must be quoted. I also added the missing quote in an edit.